Insert Dynamic Section Headers using ggsave() for ggplot2 objects without using markdown
I'm trying to see if I can generate a pdf using ggsave to have section headers in the resultant pdf. In this sample code below, I have two plots, plot_a and plot_b, saved in a list that will then be exported into a pdf using pdf.
list_objects <- c()

plot_a <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = drat))+
  geom_line()

list_objects[[1]] <- plot_a

plot_b <- ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt))+
  geom_line()

list_objects[[2]] <- plot_b

ggsave(
  filename = "Test.pdf",
  device = "pdf",
  plot = gridExtra::marrangeGrob(plot_object, nrow=1, ncol=1, top = NULL),
  width = 11, height = 11
)

If I open the pdf, the navigational pane is empty (See screenshot below). Is there a way to add headers to each plot so that they appear in the navigational pane?

EDIT: To be clear, I'm trying to see if I can create a table of contents in the navigation pane (for example, by pulling plot titles). The actual scenario is that I'll be generating 1000s of plots in this pdf, and it would be great to quickly navigate to the correct section without scrolling through to find the right figure.

Could you use Rmarkdown or Quarto to create the PDF with a TOC like this?
You could automate this to generate the headers for multiple plots.
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

## Plot A

```{r}
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = drat))+
  geom_line()
```

## Plot B

```{r, echo=FALSE}
ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = wt))+
  geom_line()
```



Sorry, I might have been unclear in my question, I was more looking to see if i can create a table of contents in the navigation pane so that I can quickly navigate to the correct section of my pdf. The actual scenario I'm facing is that I'm generating thousands of plots in a pdf, and it would be great to be able to quickly navigate to the correct section. I'll edit my question above to reflect this.

No worries. Updated for a possible approach with Rmarkdown (.Rmd) or Quarto (.qmd). You can suppress the code and only show the plots if required.

And added a link on how to automate it in Rmarkdown for many plots with headers.

Thank you for the update! Unfortunately I'm trying to avoid a .rmd solution. This script is intended as a function that can be called and integrated to other team members' workflows, so as much as a .rmd with a dynamically generated header would work for me, I'm worried it wouldn't be scalable in the scenario I'm thinking. I am fully aware there may not be a non-rmd solution though.

There's a relevant ggsave issue here that's being worked on. Maybe worth asking if headers to support a TOC could be incorporated?
